# Making a button enabled as soon as text entered in a textbox with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout-2.0.0.
I've got a button, textbox, and a viewmodel. I am disabling the Save button if there is no text in the textbox.

0">Save

This all works fine except that it requires the user to click on another part of the page to make the save button enable/disable.
i.e. it does not happen as soon as the user starts typing (or deletes all the text).

Is there away to do this in knockout.js?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you will end up wanting validation too. Check out https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation

Answer (score 1):

It should update straight away providing you are using 'valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' for the binding, look at this example from Knockout's website illustrating this behaviour:

[Simple list example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/simpleList.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `value` binding handler, then you can use the `valueUpdate` binding to change when it updates. You could change it to `keyup` instead of the default `change`. [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html).